# How to run C# class library which is added to VB.NET existing solution?

Tags: c#, vb.net, console-application

Hi I have console application which is written in VB.NET. For this I added c# class library with existing solution. I wrote code in c# class library. Now when I try to run, it is going to VB.NET console application by default. I am not able to run my c# class library.

For clear understanding lets call VB.NET project as classVB and class library as classC#

**I tired these methods to make it work :**

1) Added classC# reference to my classVB project and made classVB as startup project. I used using statement also to refer to my classVB project as `Using classVB`.  And I put break point in my classC#.But still it is pointing to classVB project

2) Tried to made classC# as startup project( Even I knew this doesn't gonna work). For this I am getting usual error which says "**A project with an output Type of class library cannot be started directly**."

3) Right click on solution and start up project option -> Single startup project and selected classVB.

But none of this is working. It is always pointing to my classVB project even after I put breakpoint on c#class library code.

Its the first time I am working on library class, so any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly run a class library.  It is not executable.  You can reference the code from it in your VB project, but a class library can never run by itself.  To access a public method in your class library from VB, refer to it by `Namespace.ClassName.MethodName`.

Comment: To clarify, you need to add your C# class library as a reference in your VB .NET application. You will then need to call the method you are trying to debug in your VB .NET application.

Answer (score 0):

Change the compilation output of the library to the same path where you added the reference in the VB.NET application. Generate the library and check the build is successful.

Do not forget to change the library class to configuration **debug** in the solution to generate the PDB file that will allow you debugging. Put a breakpoint and try again.

Comment: Hi I changed my output directory to my class library folder and I changed in configuration to debug.But still it is pointing to VB.NET even after I put break point in class library..

Comment: You have to set your startup project to the vb.net executable. Change the output directory of the C# library to the vb.net reference location. The configuration debug must be in the solution. It should work ok

Comment: Don't know.But I followed your steps but its not working. Sorry to bugging you.